# Using setTimeout to obfuscate a form from spam bots

Tags: javascript, bots, spam-prevention

Not really a coding question, more theoretical and code is not needed as I know how to do it, but I'm not sure where else to ask this.

I have an idea for preventing spam bots from seeing that I have a form, but I cannot test this in local code. Can I just make the form completely javascript generated, and then write it to the inner html of a tag after a one second timeout? Seems too easy so there must be some reason why this wouldn't work. I can't find where anybody tried this and tested it for a while so I don't know if it will work or not.

So based on what anybody knows about how bots work, can they still see that I have a form, especially if the js is obfuscated? I would think that the bot would never wait around to receive this or detect the change in the html, but would it find the form in obfuscated js?

Comment: *"I would think that the bot would never wait around to receive this or detect the change in the html"* I think that's probably underestimating the sophistication of spam bots. But I don't have anything specific to back that up.

Comment: I think that `appendChild` in `setTimeout` should work like a charm

Comment: I don't understand whats wrong with relying on tried and tested methods such as Google's latest ReCAPTCHA implementation. You have to also assume this is very un-userfriendly, having to wait a set delay before the elements of the form are rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's search spider claims that it can run some/most JavaScript when it evaluates a page, so I think it is reasonable to expect that at least some spam bots can do this now, and more so in the future.

Additionally, some spam bots are actually real people working for a pittance, using real browsers, so overall this will not work in the long term.

Comment: I know they can perform clicks and other javascript and basically operate the page as a user, but would the phony user wait around for the results of the timeOut? And if so, how long?

Comment: @Bobh - I'd wait 10 seconds ... but, do you want real users to wait that long?

Comment: The form is set to display none and needs a click to display it. I doubt the user would even click the link in the first sec of page load, and if they do, it's comes back as an empty section. If they click again, they see it. If someone is manually looking through the page, then as far as I'm concerned, they are a human, and acceptable

Comment: A bot could be written to recognise that timeout statements exist, and either short-cut them, or simply wait around the exact amount of time needed. Real users won't know that a delay exists, and may leave your page thinking it is broken, though human spam bots are just as likely to stay as a real user is.

Comment: If the phony user can read a setTimeOut in obfuscated js, then it can read the form itself in the js most likely. So I guess the answer above is most likely correct.

Comment: If no other answers appear soon, I'll mark above as answered. I'm going to try and split the form tags into variables and build them in a way where I add the vars together, and add it's tags when I do that and make it as confusing as possible, especially after obfuscated.

Comment: @Bobh I think you should check out nbokmans comment to your question.

Comment: I did. Google recaptcha does NOT work yet. I just got frustrated by a latest version the other day. Took for 4 long tries,  and this is exactly why I am trying to avoid using them. The form isn't supposed to be seen immediately, and requires a click to be seen, so no problem to users. I'm marking the answer as answered because I think it can still read the form in js